# How to set a max width for a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table inside bootstrap row / col. My table contains a long text without spaces and 
I got a horizontal scroll bar within my responsive design.

What CSS style shall I use to tell browser to automatically wrap my text?

Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">  
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td>__atuvc=6%7C39; .ASPXAUTH=7E4FE4377E9120F98FA8AB09DAFCE4BAB0539C81D51459FDBDDF8985BC16F2B7D471097C3806D9EFDC650C4810170C325A071A8A69AFA506262CE776B9D7C9595CA0FD1F856D7BC7B60EFEC9B602DE6BF98FFD0F20C62BC3E8E61E6B95199B37550D888A8FD3EEDE36287C7E86EEEE2AB600FD34D3E6E817403B631AF47C388B
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
td {
  word-wrap:break-word;
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

Working demo here: http://bootply.com/92539